# Handling timezones in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, timezone

I'm testing out making an entry system but the problem is, my host's timezone is different from where I live. It's 3am on my server while on my local computer, the time is 4pm. How do I automatically adjust code that I pull from the database to be displayed as a timezone similar to where I'm at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default timezone using the function date_default_timezone_set(). It sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

Have a look at this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

You can find a list of timezones here

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Alternatively you could change the php.ini file if you have the permissions for it. You could change the option date.timezone to your timezone like this:

```
date.timezone = "US/Central"
```

For more information about date.timezone, go to this website:

http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_change_the_datetimezone_value_in_PHP.html

Comment: you beat me to posting the exact same links by seconds :D

Comment: But what if I want to retrieve the date and format it according to where my visitor is from? E.g., I posted something at 5pm on my local time. Another visitor viewed my site but that visitor should see the local version of my time on his/her area.

Comment: You should detect the visitor's timezone code. You could do this with JavaScript. I've found a website which might give you the solution: http://onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/